# Running API javascript from bash

Tags: javascript, bash, command-line, automation, command

Hi I would like to run this script with bash command. I already installed node

How can I run this? Also I would like to parse some variable example node bb.js NiceTitle ./file.txt

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://binbox.io/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BB = new Binbox.API("http://api.binbox.io/");
    BB.create({
        title: "here the NiceTitle from command",
        text: "Here a path to ./file.txt",
    }, function(result)
    {
        console.log(result);

        if(result.ok)
        {
            console.log(result.id, result.salt);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(result.error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Create a node module and then run it with `node <modulename>`.

Answer (score 2):

Make js file with

```
var BB = new Binbox.API("http://api.binbox.io/");
BB.create({
    title: "here the NiceTitle from command",
    text: "Here a path to ./file.txt",
}, function(result)
{
    console.log(result);

    if(result.ok)
    {
        console.log(result.id, result.salt);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(result.error);
    }
});
```

content (for example file.js), then you can run with

```
node file.js
```

or from bash

P.S. Sure you will need require in the top to include lib

P.P.S. For arguments parsing there is process.argv
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv